# Server mirroring and virtual ip

Tags: php, ip-address, moodle

I´m new on this and I will appreciate a lot your help.

I have a domain ex: example.com, pointing to a public and unique IP (ex: 25.46.345.85). My Moodle is working in server #1 and being replicated in server #2.

Server #1 has an IP (example: 48.46.345.216).

Server #2 has another IP (example: 21.49.252.26).

Let's assume that the domain is working with the server #1.

What I want to do is that if server #1 goes down, the main domain keeps working automatically with the server #2 without changing the IP or anything in the domain DNS, I mean the site must never go down. How can I do this? Should I use virtual IP for the domain and this virtual IP is working with 2 IP?, would this work? does anyone have a better solution? How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

`48.46.345.216` sends a heartbeat to `25.46.345.85`. If the heartbeat is not received for a certain amount of time, `25.46.345.85` connects to `21.49.252.26` instead of to `48.46.345.216` for Moodle.

Comment: Oswald, thank you for your reply, but I would love information about server structure giving high-availability if it´s possible 100%, there  are many solutions but all of them have a risk like the Load Balancer can crash or just failed, etc.

Comment: You will get 100% only if none of your components can fail. If `48.46.345.216` can fail with a probability of x within a day, and `21.49.252.26` is a clone of `48.46.345.216`, then `21.49.252.26` will fail with a probability of x within a day. Then the probability that both will fail within a day is x², which is (given that x>0) smaller than x, but still > 0.

Comment: You talk about a load balancer in your comment. You did not say anything about a load balancer in your question. High availability is not something that can be argued on an abstract basis like that. You can get as close to 100% as you like by throwing enough money at it. However, at some point, the additional money to improve availability is more than what you lose in case of unexpected downtime.